# Change CSS checkbox border color in event listener

Tags: javascript, css

These little code snippets resemble two custom CSS checkboxes, based on this [article](https://www.kallmanation.com/styling-a-checkbox-with-only-css).

For your convenience: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jamacoe/nL942u1h/106/).

I have two problems with this code:

1. If clicking the 1st checkbox to unchecked, I want the event listener function to change the border's color of checkbox 1 to red. Methinks I'd have to change the object's `:before` properties? Anyway, I can't figure out how it's done and don't want to use jquery, font awesome or other external libraries, just pure CSS and js.
2. The 2nd checkbox is intentionally not working. In order to make it work, I'd have to embrace the `<input>` with the `<label>` statements like in checkbox 1. Why doesn't it work with `<label for="...">`? Actually I'd like to get rid of the labels alltogether.

HTML:

```js
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", () => {

  const e = event.srcElement;

  /* HOW CAN I CHANGE THE BORDER'S COLOR ONCLICK ? */

  console.log(e.style);

  if (e.checked) {
    e.style.bordercolor = 'gray';
  } else {
    e.style.borderColor = 'red';
    e.style.borderBlockColor = 'red';
    e.style.accentColor = 'red';
    e.style.borderAfterColor = 'red';
    e.style.borderBeforeColor = 'red';
    e.style.outlineColor = 'red';
    e.style.overrideColors = 'red';
  }

});
```

```css
.cbx {
  display: none;
  /* hide the regular checkbox */
}

.cbx+*::before {
  /* settings if checkbox is unchecked */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  border-radius: 10%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1rem;
  content: "";
  /* no mark */
  border-color: gray;
  /* border color DON'T CHANGE IT HERE TO RED. Initially it should be gray */
  background: pink;
  /* background */
}

.cbx+* {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: purple;
  /* label color if unchecked */
}

.cbx:checked+* {
  color: red;
  /* label color if checked */
}

.cbx:checked+*::before {
  /* settings if checked */
  content: "X";
  /* the check mark */
  color: white;
  /* mark's color */
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
  /* background if checked */
  border-color: yellow;
  /* border if checked */
}
```

```html
<form>

  <label>
        <input id="first" class="cbx" type="checkbox" />
        <span>First</span>
      </label>

  <!-- 2nd NOT WORKING IF <label> doesn't embrace <input> like in checkbox 1. WHY NOT? -->

  <label for="second">Second</label>
  <input id="second" class="cbx" type="checkbox" name="second" />

</form>
```

Comment: Your second one does not show the box because there is no element after the input that the css rule is looking for....

Comment: And I have no clue what your issue is with issue #1.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for making the snippet work in here. Still have to figure out how to do that. --- So because all CSS statements use +* and thus direct subsequent sibling and checkbox 2 hasn't got one, it doesn't work? Did I get that right? Alternativly <div><input><span></span></div> won't work either, so it really has to be <label>? --- Regarding Issue 1: If unchecking the checkbox 1, it's border should turn from yellow to red, not gray (which is the initial border color).

Comment: So put the label after it. `<input id="second" class="cbx" type="checkbox" name="second" />
  <label for="second">Second</label>`

Comment: `e.style.bordercolor = 'gray';` <--- Case Matters

Comment: @epascarello so the label thing is clear. In order to get rid of the label statements alltogether, I would have to rewrite the whole CSS to not address +* siblings that are not present. --- Case: DevTools ( console.log(e.style) ) tell me it is borderColor. Anyway, it doesn't work. And it's the other branch (else) I'm asking about: If clicked to unchecked, show border red. I have found no way how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra CSS class for the red border to override .cbx + *::before

```
.cbx.redBorder + *::before {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Add and remove this class to the checkbox onclick:

```
document.getElementById("cb").addEventListener("click", () => {
    var e=event.srcElement;
    if (e.checked) {
        e.classList.remove("redBorder");
    } else {
        e.classList.add("redBorder");
    }
});
```

Toggle won't work because the checkbox starts unchecked and thus can't remove redBorder if clicked.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamacoe/nL942u1h/119/